# get the path of a module in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-3.2

One can get the path of the current script with `os.path.pathname(sys.argv[0])`. But how can i get the path of a module which isn't the executed script and instead the script imported the module. I need it to read a configuration file for a module which should be in the same folder as the module but the module could be installed anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import os
import your_module

# Get directory of your module
print os.path.dirname(your_module.__file__)
```

Demo:

```
import os
import re

print os.path.dirname(re.__file__)
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
```